# Add several local Jars as Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have 50 jars that I need to add to a Maven project as dependencies. They are not in the public repository, I cannot install a local repository and I'd like to know a quick solution to add them in my pom.xml.

I know that to add a local dependency you could write

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

but this is simply a real long task with several Jars. Is there an easy way to do it?

The solutions suggested in [How to add local jar files in maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project) are specific for a single or few Jars but not the case when you many of them.

Comment: Start using a repository manager and install them there and use them as dependencies that's it...

Comment: I am using a corporate workstation where I am not allowed to install a repository manager. The only solution that I found so far is to write my own script to generate the <dependency>...<systemPath>...code.

Comment: Could you please share your solution, I have same usecase.

Answer (score -1):

Add those jars to your local maven repository and then add their dependency to your POM. See this link: [MKYong: How to include custom library into maven local repository?](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)

Comment: "I cannot install a local repository"

Comment: @LucaS. All maven installations include a local repository.  That's how maven *works*.  If you have maven, you have a local repository already, and you can already install artifacts into it.